CGAL Use same Point_2 for 2D Linear and 2D Circular operations
I'm trying to determine if its possible to use the same Point_2 objects in CGAL to compute intersections with Polygon_2s and Circle_2s.
I have the following:
    typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                                             LinearKernel;
    typedef CGAL::Algebraic_kernel_for_circles_2_2<LinearKernel::RT>                                        AlgebraicKernel;
    typedef CGAL::Filtered_bbox_circular_kernel_2<CGAL::Circular_kernel_2<LinearKernel, AlgebraicKernel>>   CircularKernel;
    typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<LinearKernel>                                                                   Polygon2;
    typedef LinearKernel::Point_2                                                                           Point2;
    typedef LinearKernel::Line_2                                                                            Line2;
    typedef LinearKernel::Segment_2                                                                         Segment2;
    typedef CGAL::Circle_2<CircularKernel>                                                                  Circle2;
    typedef CircularKernel::Point_2                                                                         CPoint2;
    typedef CircularKernel::Line_2                                                                          CLine2;
    typedef CircularKernel::Segment_2                                                                       CSegment2;

But I want something more like
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                                             LinearKernel;
typedef CGAL::Algebraic_kernel_for_circles_2_2<LinearKernel::RT>                                        AlgebraicKernel;
typedef CGAL::Filtered_bbox_circular_kernel_2<CGAL::Circular_kernel_2<LinearKernel, AlgebraicKernel>>   CircularKernel;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<LinearKernel>                                                                   Polygon2;
typedef LinearKernel::Point_2                                                                           Point2;
typedef LinearKernel::Line_2                                                                            Line2;
typedef LinearKernel::Segment_2                                                                         Segment2;
typedef CGAL::Circle_2<CircularKernel>                                                                  Circle2;

For example, consider wanting to determine if a line intersects with a polygon and also intersects with another circle. We can use CGAL::intersection() to do this. However, if I use the Line_2 from the latter definitions with a Circle_2, I get a compiler error.
Alternatively, is there a way to easily convert between kernels?

This is not a C++ code, this is smth meaningless. Can you post smth more close to a real code?
